# rotate text on the button

Tags: android, button, android-framelayout

I'm having the following screen:

[image]

And I'm trying to rotate a text and then set the text on this button.

For that I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<SurfaceView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/surface_camera" />


<FrameLayout 
android:layout_width="60dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
  <Button           android:layout_width="60dip"
                     android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

 <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="60dip"
                     android:id="@+id/textview"
                     android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  />

</FrameLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And then I try to use animations in order to rotate my text :

File:`res/anim/myanim:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromDegrees="0" 
       android:toDegrees="-90"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="0" />
```

And then I do in `onCreate()`:

```
te = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
      te.setText(t);

     RotateAnimation ranim = (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanim);
     ranim.setFillAfter(true);
    te.setAnimation(ranim);
```

But unfortunately no text appears on my button.Anyone any ideas?

Comment: What abt    te.setVisibility(true);

Comment: what do u mean by not working? u want me to write the entire code for u or what? I said use the following code te.setVisibility(true); first u try to improve ur English to understand comments.

Comment: I said that I get error at that line.I don't have problems with english!!!!

Comment: u can also check this link http://www.barebonescoder.com/tag/android-animation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder named anim and then create xml file and add this below xml

```
<rotate 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0" 
android:toDegrees="360" 
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
 android:repeatCount="infinite" 
 android:duration="1200" />
```

then add below line on textview in xml where you defined your textView.

```
android:interpolator="@anim/linear_interpolator"
```

and final apply below code...

```
Animation logoMoveAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Animation2DActivity.this,
                    R.anim.linear_interpolator);
            mobjectImageButton.startAnimation(logoMoveAnimation);
```

enjoy.